# Developer console

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

Hello I came across jobs where you let others to publish their apps in your developer console and they give you money and is this harmfull for your account? Why don't they just buy their membership with this money?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 possible reasons for this

1- they probably have some malicious code or sketchy thing going on
2- they might have a genuine application and they just don't want to spend the 25$ or go through the hassle of uploading the app themselves

now which of the 2 is it? ur guess would be as good as mine, as a general rule, i would never upload an app if i haven't participated in it's development myself, but to each their own.

Comment: The unusual is that they pay 25$. In this price they can buy their own account membership :D